# How do I keep my javascript styles after a menu button is clicked and that new page loads?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make my navbar menu items have a specific style when the user is in that specific page using Javascript. So far I am able to change the style when the button is clicked, but once that new page loads, the styles disappear and the menu items are all the same again. How do I keep the styles so the page's button (the one the user is currently in) has the special style.

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
    <a id="home" class="active">HOME</a>
    <a id="automobile" class="">AUTO</a>
</div>
```

Edit 2: Ok so I am very close!  Everything works, except that it will remove the active class from the home button, but once the new page reloads, it will add it back again and i'm stuck with two  buttons with the active link class.  What is the solution for this?  Here is my new code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('nav #navbar_menu .navbar-nav a').removeClass("active");
            var activeIndex = $(this).index();
            var activeIndex = activeIndex + 1;
            localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', activeIndex);
        });      
    });

   var activeIndex = localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue');
    if (isNaN(activeIndex)) {
        console.log('nothing stored');
    } else {
        $('a:nth-child('+activeIndex+')').addClass('active');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You simply create and if statement to check what page you're currently on. You can do it by checking what the URL is with JS.

Comment: Why not just use `css` and create a class style, for each page related to that link give it that class.... Once the page reloads `javascript` returns to it's default state so any changes made client-side will be lost.

Comment: use `active` tag for doing your stuff

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you load the content of your page, I can think of two possibilities to choose from. When loading a new URL upon clicking a button, use a class attached to the selected element. When using AJAX to load content (excluding the navigation), use a CSS pseudo-class.

### URL load

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

a {
  background: lightblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.active {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  Page content
</section>
```

For each page the active class will be attached to a different menu element.

### AJAX load

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

a {
  background: lightblue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  Page content
</section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is what i'm asking for.  I edited my post to reflect some changes I made.  Thanks regardless!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution using PHP and not Javascript. Here it is:

```
<?php $page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>

<div class="navbar-nav">
    <a id="home" class="<?php if ($page == 'index.php'){echo 'active'; } ?>">HOME</a>
    <a id="automobile" class="<?php if ($page == 'automobile.php'){echo 'active'; } ?>">AUTO</a>
</div>
```

Much easier than using Javascript!

Answer (score -1):

you can use localstroage to store the color and get it back on that page load(onready function)

To store the color:

```
localStorage.setItem("mycolor","#COLORCODEHERE");
```

on the bottom of the next page

```
<script>

(function() {
  var color= localStorage.getItem("mycolor");
/*
    your code here
*/

})();
</script>
```

check this link : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I would recommend you update your answer and include the relevant source code with a brief description of how it can be used and how it will help solve the existing problem. Link only answers should be placed in the comments section if anywhere.